# How to use trigger event in facebook messenger bot

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm developing Facebook messenger bot. Based on the official sample
[here](https://github.com/fbsamples/messenger-bot-samples/tree/master/account-linking) made by Node.js, Express, ES7.

I want to use Firebase database, [trigger event](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data?hl=en).

If someone updates the database, send notice to certain people. I add source code "Child Changed" to "messages.js" in messenger-api-helpers, but it doesn't work. 
I can check working "Child Changed" in HTML, but in messenger, I cannot.

Where should I write the trigger events code?

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use [Facebook Messenger Broadcast API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/broadcast-messages) for this kind of functionality. This will broadcast a notice/broadcast to users.

Caveats:

1. You have to apply for this permission. (pages_messaging and pages_messaging_subscriptions.Takes about 1-2 days, but
   can test on Admin/Test users of the app)
2. Each broadcast has to be a separate broadcast. (e.g. you can't send image and a text together, each has to be its own individual broadcast).
3. Have some kind of un-subscription option as well. FB user might think you are spamming even if you clearly say in the messages that your bot will send updates.
4. Use [custom labels](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/broadcast-messages/target-broadcasts) to create targetted sends. So you can either subdivide who you will send updates to about specific issues or just label people if they unsubscribe to your broadcast or not.

Basic workflow:

1. Get permission to broadcast.
2. On event in your Database. Start process.
3. Create message_creative_id via POST to endpoint
4. Use message_creative_id to POST a broadcast_messages
5. On a successful send you will get back broadcast_id